# How to modify directive scope attribute only from the inside

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a custom directive that requires another custom directive as a parent:

```
 .directive('controlErrorContainer', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'template/common/control_error_container.html',
        require: '^controlContainer',
 ...
 });
```

The control_error_container.html looks like this:

```
<div class="label label-danger" ng-show="isValid" ng-transclude>
</div>
```

So in the end, an html page that uses these tags would look like this:

```
<control-container control-to-check="stuff">
    <input id="stuff" name="stuff" ng-model="stuff" />
    <control-error-container>
           You have failed me for the last time admiral!
    </control-error-container>
</control-container>
```

What I had in mind is that control-container stores the reference to the control it supposed to hold and check and control-error-container only shows the errors in it if the observed controller has any validation issues.

I have a problem with the fact that I want the controlErrorContainer to run without any attributes from the outside. As you can see, it has an ng-show tag with an "isValid" value defined. This value is unnecessary because the value of the control's validity can be obtained via the parent custom directive's container (and I do this).
This is not working and I don't know how to make it work since upon creation of the controller, it has to be defined somewhere. If I create a scope with it with 2 way binding, angular throws an exception.

So the question is how can I make this work without forcing the user to create an unnecessary attribute?

Comment: Do you want to have access to parent directive's `isValid` variable? Then you can use `ng-show="$parent.isValid"`. I'm not sure if I understand what you mean, fiddle or plunkr would be great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, you're trying to build something like a validation framework. Since angular already provides one, I recommend to try to use it.

Angular's [validation framework](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/docs/api/ng/directive/form) is built on `FormController` and `NgModelController` which are some short of collaborating controllers inside `form` and `ngModel` directives.

Adding custom validators is simply writting a directive to hook you validation function into the framework. An example of such a validator is:

```
app.directive('validUserType', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: '?ngModel',
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        var allowAdmin = attrs.allowAdmin && attrs.allowAdmin === 'true';

        if (ngModelCtrl) {
          ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(userTypeValidator);
          ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(userTypeValidator);
        }

        function userTypeValidator(value) {
          if (!value || value === 'guest' || (allowAdmin && value === 'admin')) {
            ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('validUserType', true);
            return value;
          } else {
            ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('validUserType', false);
            return;
          }
        }
      }
    };
});
```

Which you apply as:

```
<input name="input" ng-model="userType" required valid-user-type allow-admin="true">
```

Notice that you can have as many validators as you like (`required` is also a validator provided by angular) and they are no diferrent than a normal directive which has additional attributes (`allow-admin="true"`). What makes it a validator is the way it integrates with `ngModel`. You add a "parser" for when the user provides input, and a formatter for when the value is changed by javascript code. In addition to validation, it can also act as a converter, i.e. convert string -> object (in the parser) and vice versa (in the formatter). In that case you need 2 separate functions, not a common one.

Angular's framework takes care of all the rest. It maintains validity "flags" at the input/specific validator/form level, which can be used to show/hide validation messages or enable/disable buttons. It also maintains CSS classes which can be used to add visual sugar and "dirty" flags to inform the user which fields have been edited. More importantly, it will allow only valid values (or `undefined`) to propagate to your model, meaning that if you have something like this in your controller:

```
$scope.$watch('userType', function(userType) {
    if (userType) {
        // make ajax with userType
    }
});
```

it is guaranteed that only valid `userType` values will be sent to the server.

Bottom line: it already provides a lot and it is officially maintained, so it makes sense to built on top of it.

Check out this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MPO9Q6WdRCa5M9Ux0YnG?p=preview) (cooked up the plunker from the angular docs).

Of course, you can build your own validation framework with `control-container` and `control-error-container`. What your example is missing is how the actual validator will hook into the game. My preference is to apply it on the input element, much like angular validators are applied:

```
<control-container>
  <input ng-model="userType" valid-user-type allow-admin="true"/>
  <control-error-container>
    You have failed me for the last time admiral!
  </control-error-container>
</control-container>
```

`valid-user-type` is your custom validator which communicates its result to `control-container` and then from `control-container` down to `control-error-container`. These 3 directives are something like:

```
app.directive('controlContainer', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    controller: function() {
      var controlErrorContainer = null;

      this.setValid = function(value) {
        if (controlErrorContainer) controlErrorContainer.setValid(value);
      }

      this.setControlErrorContainer = function(cec) {
        controlErrorContainer = cec;
      }
    },
    templateUrl: 'controlContainer.html'
  };
});

app.directive('controlErrorContainer', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    require: ['controlErrorContainer', '^controlContainer'],
    templateUrl: 'controlErrorContainer.html',
    controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.isValid = true;
      this.setValid = function(value) {
        $scope.isValid = value;
      };
    }],
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, controllers) {
      var controlErrorContainer = controllers[0];
      var controlContainer = controllers[1];
      controlContainer.setControlErrorContainer(controlErrorContainer);
    }
  };
});

app.directive('validUserType', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: ['ngModel', '^controlContainer'],
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, controllers) {
      var allowAdmin = attrs.allowAdmin && attrs.allowAdmin === 'true';

      var ngModel = controllers[0];
      var controlContainer = controllers[1];

      scope.$watch(
        function() {
          return ngModel.$viewValue;
        },
        function(value) {
          if (!value || value === 'guest' || (allowAdmin && value === 'admin')) {
            controlContainer.setValid(true);
          } else {
            controlContainer.setValid(false);
          }
        }
      );
    }
  };
});
```

you *could* do something like `<control-container control-to-check="stuff">` but I think it more to difficult to find "stuff" and its value and run a validator on it (which I don't see how you it is defined).

Check out the complete [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9baj3E1VS2q8BZ1Didxj?p=preview).